# Telegram bot (using aiogram): User verification

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

I'm making a Telegram bot for work purposes. For confidentiality reasons I need to implement a identification check upon starting the bot.

I'm getting a list of employees IDs who are given access to the bot from a database. It is updated every day.
When a user starts the bot, it asks for the ID. The user is supposed to reply with their ID.
The bot then is supposed to check if this ID is in the list downloaded from the database.
If it is, the bot gives access to the information. If not, it replies with something like "Sorry, you are not a verified user. For getting access, please contact Kate or try again."
Also, it needs to check this information every day - since a list of employees can change every day (for example, in case one of the employees on the list quit their job).

I haven't been able to find suitable solutions on the Internet or come up with one that works for me.
Please help me out with ideas - I'm still new to Python and only just started learning about aiogram.

Things I have tried:

1. I managed to make the bot respond to 'XXXXXXX' with "verification succeeded" lol:

```
dp.register_message_handler(handlers.start, commands=["start"])
dp.register_message_handler(handlers.verify_user, text=["XXXXXXX"])

user_id_list = ['YYYYYYY', 'XXXXXXX', 'ZZZZZZ'] 


# start
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Hi there! For verification please write your ID in this format: XXXXXXX.")

# verification
async def verify_user(message: types.Message):
    if message.text in user_id_list:
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="get report", callback_data="get_report"))
        await message.answer("You have been identified!", reply_markup=keyboard)
    else:
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="try again", callback_data="/start"))
        await message.answer("Sorry, you are not a verified user. For getting access, please contact Kate or try again.", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

2. I also tried using Text filter like this:

```
id_list = ['XXXXX', 'YYYYY']

dp.register_message_handler(handlers.verification, filters.Text(contains=id_list, ignore_case=True))

async def verification(message: types.Message):
     keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
     keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="get report", callback_data="get_report"))
     await message.answer("You have been identified!", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

but this only works if you include the whole id_list in your message (i.e. XXXXX YYYYY).

3. Another thing I tried is IDFilter but seems like it only works with numbers - and our IDs are str.
4. Finally, I tried creating a State and using FSM but I can't quite understand what this is doing: it checks my ID fine, but after that the bot does nothing. Moreover, if I restart the bot, it doesn't ask me for my ID, it tells me straight away that my ID is wrong (it sees '/start' as an ID input, I guess). The code is below:

```
id_list = ['XXXXX', 'YYYYY']

class Form(StatesGroup):
    work_id = State()

dp.register_message_handler(handlers.set_work_id, state=Form.work_id)

async def start(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hi there! What is your ID?')
    await Form.work_id.set()

async def set_work_id(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text in id_list:
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="get report", callback_data="get_report"))
        await message.answer("You have been verified!", reply_markup=keyboard)
    else:
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Try again", callback_data="/start"))
        await message.answer("Sorry, you are not a verified user. For getting access, please contact Kate or try again.", reply_markup=keyboard)
```